# Failed to control fan speed for Nvidia Geforce 1060 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gpu, fancontrol, nvidia-settings

My current Ubuntu kernel is 4.12.5 with Nvidia driver 384.69.

However, since the upgrade, the GPU always performes at highest (level 4) performance level, so the GPU fan is running all the time.

I have tried to put the "RegisterDWord" in the xorg.conf, but it didn't work.

And for the nvidia-settings, `nvidia-settings -q fans` had no output, so I **cannot** control fan by using `nvidia-settings -a [fan:0]/GPUTargetSpeed=`

Can anyone suggest what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using dell, use the following utility

```
sudo apt-get install i8kutils 
i8kfan 1 2 # Set the left-fan at low speed(1); the right one at high speed(2).
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not. Purchased from System 76. Will this still work if it is not a dell computer?